# Найти объект с помощью перебора массива

Tags: javascript

Есть select нужно с помощью перебора массива вывести ключ(red,blue,green) к   которому относится значение select, то-есть если мы выбираем в  select  "Академгородок" то  при нажатии на кнопку должен вывестись red(ключ там где находится этот объект).HTML:

```
<select id="select_2">
    <option value="Академгородок">Академгородок</option>
    <option value="ТЧ-2 «Оболонь»">ТЧ-2 «Оболонь»</option>
    <option value="Сырец">Сырец</option>
</select>
<button class="btn_2">Push</button>
```

Js:

```
let sel_2 = document.querySelector('#select_2');
let btn_2 = document.querySelector('.btn_2');

btn_2.onclick = function func_2() {
  stat = sel_2.value;
  for(let key in metro) {
      for(let i = 0; i < metro[key]; i++) {

      }
   }
}
```

массив:

```
const metro = {
"red" : [
  'Академгородок', 'Житомирская', 'Святошин', 'Нивки',
  'Берестейская', 'Шулявская', 'Политехнический институт',
  'Вокзальная', 'Университет', 'Крещатик', 'Арсенальная',
  'Гидропарк', 'Левобережная', 'Дарница', 'Лесная'
  ],
"blue" : [
  'ТЧ-2 «Оболонь»', 'Героев Днепра', 'Оболонь', 'Почайна',
  'Тараса Шевченко', 'Почтовая площадь', 'Майдан Незалежности', 'Олимпийская',
  'Дворец «Украина»', 'Лыбедская', 'Демиевская', 'Голосеевская', 'Теремки'
],
"green" : [
  'Сырец', 'Дорогожичи', 'Герцена', 'Лукьяновская',
  'Львовская брама', 'Золотые ворота', 'Дворец спорта', 'Крещатику',
  'Печерская', 'Дружбы народов', 'Выдубичи', 'Теличка',
  'Славутич', 'Красный хутор', 'Улица Горбунова',
]
}
```

Comment: А что у тебя не получается сделать? В чем вопрос, а не задание?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const metro = {
 "red" : [
   'Академгородок', 'Житомирская', 'Святошин', 'Нивки',
   'Берестейская', 'Шулявская', 'Политехнический институт',
   'Вокзальная', 'Университет', 'Крещатик', 'Арсенальная',
   'Гидропарк', 'Левобережная', 'Дарница', 'Лесная'
   ],
 "blue" : [
   'ТЧ-2 «Оболонь»', 'Героев Днепра', 'Оболонь', 'Почайна',
   'Тараса Шевченко', 'Почтовая площадь', 'Майдан Незалежности', 'Олимпийская',
   'Дворец «Украина»', 'Лыбедская', 'Демиевская', 'Голосеевская', 'Теремки'
 ],
 "green" : [
   'Сырец', 'Дорогожичи', 'Герцена', 'Лукьяновская',
   'Львовская брама', 'Золотые ворота', 'Дворец спорта', 'Крещатику',
   'Печерская', 'Дружбы народов', 'Выдубичи', 'Теличка',
   'Славутич', 'Красный хутор', 'Улица Горбунова',
 ]
};

let btn = document.querySelector(".btn_2");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
 let select = document.querySelector("#select_2");
 let text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].textContent;

 window.console.log(getKey(metro, text));
});

function getKey(obj, val) {
 for (let prop of Object.keys(obj)) {
  if (metro[prop].includes(val)) return prop;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <select id="select_2">
     <option value="Академгородок">Академгородок</option>
     <option value="ТЧ-2 «Оболонь»">ТЧ-2 «Оболонь»</option>
     <option value="Сырец">Сырец</option>
 </select>
 <button class="btn_2">Push</button>
</body>
</html>
```